# OpenCV error on Mac OS M2 when using cv::Vec3f

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, g++, arm64

After building and installing OpenCV on my MacOS (M2), I wrote a c++ code that uses OpenCV to perform some tasks. However when adding this line of code :

```
std::sort(c_two_hsv_sorted.begin<cv::Vec3f>(), c_two_hsv_sorted.end<cv::Vec3f>(), customSort);
```

with customSort function defined as

```
// Custom comparison function
bool customSort(const cv::Vec3f& a, const cv::Vec3f& b) {
if (a[0] != b[0]) return a[0] > b[0];        // Sort by 1st column in descending order
if (a[2] != b[2]) return a[2] > b[2];        // Sort by 3rd column in descending order
return a[1] > b[1];                          // Sort by 2nd column in descending order
}
```

and compiling and linkig with :

```
g++ -c -o test.o fusion.cpp -I ../libigl-main/include/ -I /opt/homebrew/Cellar/eigen/3.4.0_1/include/eigen3 -I /opt/homebrew/Cellar/flann/1.9.2_1/include -I /opt/homebrew/Cellar/lz4/1.9.4/include  -I path_to_OpenCV/opencv/include/  -I path_to_OpenCV/build/  -I path_to_OpenCV/opencv/modules/core/include/
```

and

```
g++ -o out_fusion test.o    -L /opt/homebrew/Cellar/flann/1.9.2_1/lib/ -fopenmp -lflann  -L /opt/homebrew/Cellar/lz4/1.9.4/lib/  -llz4 -L path_to_OpenCV/build/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_video -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_photo -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ml -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_flann -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_videoio
```

I got the error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "__ZN2cv5errorEiRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEPKcS9_i", referenced from:
  __ZN2cv16MatConstIteratorC2EPKNS_3MatE in test.o
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

note that I builded OpenCV using these commands :

```
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
mkdir build
cmake ../opencv/ .
arch -arm64 cmake ../opencv/ -DWITH_QT=OFF -DWITH_OPENGL=OFF -DFORCE_VTK=OFF -DWITH_TBB=OFF -DWITH_GDAL=OFF -DWITH_XINE=OFF -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DBUILD_ZLIB=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF .
arch -arm64 sudo make -j 4
arch -arm64 sudo make install
```

I don't know if I missed to include or link one of the modules related to OpenCV, but I still don't find what I miss. Any help please ?